# Software for creating 2D Animations in Web-friendly format

Tags: gratis, linux, web-browser, animation

I want to create small animations in web-friendly format.

What format should I chose? I want to use an open-source format that is usable on all browsers.

What software should I use? The software needs to be easy even for a novice, should be open source and be available on Fedora Gnome.

Comment: The first question is unfortunately off-topic, but your second question is on-topic.  Perhaps the answer to the second question will indirectly indicate the answer to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Tupi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupi_%28software%29).

It is a free and open-source software application for the design and creation of 2D animation.

[Download here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tupi2d/).